# Align 2 images vertically in one column

Tags: graphics, floats, formatting, subfloats

I'm writing a paper in IEEEtran two column format. I want 2 subfigures to be aligned vertically. Here's what I'm doing:

```
\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering

\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
    \includegraphics{imgs/inbox_attach1}
    \caption{aa}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
    \includegraphics{imgs/inbox_attach2}
    \caption{bb}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Email received by the author in his inbox.}
\label{fig:inbox_attach}
\end{figure}
```

The images get placed at the end of the document and exceed the size of the page. What corrections do I need to do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. Ideally it should compile  unless, of course, that is what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because I needed to add [width=\columnwidth] after \includegraphics. For example:

```
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{imgs/inbox_attach1}
```

Please suggest if there's a better solution.